# How to update local search path for nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan?

Tags: hardhat, contract-verification, hardhat-deploy

The [documentation](https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan.html) says:

> Just provide the deployment address and constructor arguments, and the plugin will detect locally which contract to verify

however I have some contracts that only implement OpenZeppelins', e.g:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

import { ProxyAdmin } from '@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/ProxyAdmin.sol';

// prettier-ignore
contract MyProxyAdmin is ProxyAdmin {}
```

In this context `nph hardhat verify` finds two binaries matching the one found in etherscan, precisely `MyProxiAdmin.sol` and `ProxyAdmin.sol` and throws an error. I'd like not to use explicitly the `contract` argument of verify as during deployment one only used the name of the contract and not it path in the project.

How to handle this?